# Scala map elements inside a Tuple

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have a DStream with tuple of Date and String as value, I want to convert the String part of the tuple to HashSet[String], when I try to map it inside another map it is not working for some reason, here is what I tried so far, any pointers would help

```
val enTextTupleStream: DStream[(Date, String)]

def extractStrings(data: String): HashSet[String]= HashSet(data)

val ddstream = enTextTupleStream.map {            
  t =>
    val e1 = t._1
    val e2 = t._2.map(extractStrings)
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the output to be? Also, why are you `map`ing a **String** if the function already expects a **String**, what you want isn't just `extractStrings(t._2)`?

Comment: Luis you are correct, all I have to do was extractStrings(t._2). Thank you for your input, you saved my day.

Comment: It seems you are pretty new to the language I would recommend you to study it more, for example at least read the [**Tour of Scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html). Since this is just a basic function call and the question gives the impression that you are just trying random bits until something works.